# Custom C++ ASP .NET Membership Login

Tags: c++, hash, asp.net-membership

Does anyone know how can I hash the user's password using the salt key provided by the ASP .NET Membership?

I'm developing a C++ Linux application and I have only access to the SQL Server.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/xsp/system/Web/Util/SecUtil.cs) is the encoding algorithm used by ASP.Net Membership which is written in C#.

It uses `System.Security`, so you might want to look at [MONO](http://www.mono-project.com/Cryptography) if you want to run on Lunix.

**Note:** I'm not familiar with MONO.

```
private string EncodePassword(string pass, int passwordFormat, string salt)
{
    if (passwordFormat == 0) // MembershipPasswordFormat.Clear
        return pass;

    byte[] bIn = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(pass);
    byte[] bSalt = Convert.FromBase64String(salt);
    byte[] bRet = null;

    if (passwordFormat == 1)
    { // MembershipPasswordFormat.Hashed
        HashAlgorithm hm = GetHashAlgorithm();
        if (hm is KeyedHashAlgorithm)
        {
            KeyedHashAlgorithm kha = (KeyedHashAlgorithm)hm;
            if (kha.Key.Length == bSalt.Length)
            {
                kha.Key = bSalt;
            }
            else if (kha.Key.Length < bSalt.Length)
            {
                byte[] bKey = new byte[kha.Key.Length];
                Buffer.BlockCopy(bSalt, 0, bKey, 0, bKey.Length);
                kha.Key = bKey;
            }
            else
            {
                byte[] bKey = new byte[kha.Key.Length];
                for (int iter = 0; iter < bKey.Length; )
                {
                    int len = Math.Min(bSalt.Length, bKey.Length - iter);
                    Buffer.BlockCopy(bSalt, 0, bKey, iter, len);
                    iter += len;
                }
                kha.Key = bKey;
            }
            bRet = kha.ComputeHash(bIn);
        }
        else
        {
            byte[] bAll = new byte[bSalt.Length + bIn.Length];
            Buffer.BlockCopy(bSalt, 0, bAll, 0, bSalt.Length);
            Buffer.BlockCopy(bIn, 0, bAll, bSalt.Length, bIn.Length);
            bRet = hm.ComputeHash(bAll);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        byte[] bAll = new byte[bSalt.Length + bIn.Length];
        Buffer.BlockCopy(bSalt, 0, bAll, 0, bSalt.Length);
        Buffer.BlockCopy(bIn, 0, bAll, bSalt.Length, bIn.Length);
        bRet = EncryptPassword(bAll, _LegacyPasswordCompatibilityMode);
    }

    return Convert.ToBase64String(bRet);
}

private string GenerateSalt()
{
    byte[] buf = new byte[SALT_SIZE];
    (new RNGCryptoServiceProvider()).GetBytes(buf);
    return Convert.ToBase64String(buf);
}
```

Comment: Thank you Win. This is a good example. But I'm wondering If I could write something like that in C++ and not to put another layer in my app.

Comment: You can covert it C++; it is not much of the code.  [C++ to C# Code Converter](http://sourceforge.net/projects/convetercpptocs/)